# Vertical and horizontal centering text in container with no fixed size acting weird in Firefox

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

Having some trouble with implenting vertical centering.
Seems to be working as it should in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox it acts weirdly (I'm debugging on a Mac).

When the browser is resized the size of the hover element is not resized to fit it's parent, and when the browser is resized to the original width the hover element ends up too small.

See [**this video**](http://youtu.be/wHuM4WvhZ5U)

Here's the 
[**demo**](http://jsbin.com/ejutor/1). ([**Link**](http://jsbin.com/ejutor/1/edit) to code view)

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve this problem with these changes.
Hope it might come in handy for someone in the future (Link to full solution at bottom of answer).

**Original markup**

```
<article class="work-preview">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-600-414-6.jpg">
    <div class="covering background"></div>
    <div class="covering foreground">
            <h2>A Text</h2>
    </div>
</article>
```

**New markup**

```
<article class="work-preview">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-600-414-6.jpg">
        <div class="coveringcontainer">
            <div class="covering foreground">
                <h2>A Text</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
</article>
```

**Original CSS**

```
.covering {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

body .work-preview:hover .covering {
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**New CSS**

```
.coveringcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
}

.work-preview:hover .coveringcontainer {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.covering {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And here's the [**solution**](http://jsbin.com/ejutor/6/edit) in full!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `inline-block;` instead of `inline-table` on

```
body .work-preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't consider `vertical-align:middle;` because it is only considered on table-cells. If you want more information i suggest you to read [Understanding Vertically Align](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html).